# Hashtable interface, used for setting a key a instance of an object

Tags: java, hashtable

My add to hashtable method fails, what have i done wrong? Or what have i missunderstood?

test:

```
@Test
public void testAddKeyValue() {
    AdminController cont = new AdminController();

    Apartment o1 = new Apartment(1, 4, "Maier B", true);
    ArrayList<Expense> exp = new ArrayList<>();

    cont.addKeyWithList(o1, exp);
    assertTrue(cont.isEmpty()); // ISSUE > the test works if it is true, but it is supposed be  False.
}
```

repo class:

```
public class Repository extends HashMap<Apartment, ArrayList<Expense>>{
    private Map<Apartment,ArrayList<Expense>> dic; // last expense object refers to curret month
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Apartment, ArrayList<Expense>>> it;
    public void addKeyWithList(Apartment apt, ArrayList<Expense> exp){
        dic.put(apt, exp);
        }
}
```

Why is my test  not working? Or where in the code have I done something wrong?

Comment: is your code throwing an exception ?? or is it just not adding the elements into the hashtable ??

Comment: Did you implement equals() and hashcode() for the class you want to put into Hashtable?

Comment: I also don't understand why your class `extends HashMap<Apartment, ArrayList<Expense>>` and has a member variable of the same type.

Comment: And moreover you are creating addKeyWithList() method in Repository  class and you are using AdminController  class. Are both are the classes are same or what..? Will you please explain what are you doing..? And also what are you try to archive ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend HashMap as you're doing. Use a HashMap and delegate to it:

```
public class Repository {
    private Map<Apartment, List<Expense>> dic = new HashMap<Apartment, List<Expense>>();

    public void addKeyWithList(Apartment apt, ArrayList<Expense> exp){
        dic.put(apt, exp);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return dic.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

At the moment, Repository is a HashMap, but you don't store anything in it: you store the values in another HashMap contained in Repository.

Also, storing an iterator in a field is a bad idea. iterators can be used only once. Once they have iterated, the can't iterate anymore. It should be a local variable.